# SQL - group by - limit clause - postgresql

Tags: postgresql, select, group-by, limit

I have a table which has two columns C1 and C2.

C1 has an integer data type and C2 has text.

Table looks like this.

```
---C1--- ---C2---
   1    |   a    |
   1    |   b    |
   1    |   c    |
   1    |   d    |
   1    |   e    |
   1    |   f    |
   1    |   g    |
   2    |   h    |
   2    |   i    |
   2    |   j    |
   2    |   k    |
   2    |   l    |
   2    |   m    |
   2    |   n    |
------------------
```

My question: i want a sql query which does group by on column C1 but with size of 3.

looks like this.

```
------------------
   1    |  a,b,c |
   1    |  d,e,f |
   1    |   g    |
   2    |  h,i,j |
   2    |  k,l,m |
   2    |   n    |
------------------
```

is it possible by executing SQL???

Note: I do not want to write stored procedure or function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a common table expression to partition the results into rows, and then use `STRING_AGG` to join them into comma separated lists;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY C2)-1)/3 rn
  FROM mytable
)
SELECT C1, STRING_AGG(C2, ',') ALL_C2
FROM cte
GROUP BY C1,rn
ORDER BY C1
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0a88c/1).

A short explanation of the common table expression;

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (...)` will number the results from 1 to n for each value of C1. We then subtract 1 and divide by 3 to get the sequence `0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2...` and group by that value in the outer query to get 3 results per row.

Comment: thanks...its working.... :)   (m not aware of ommon table expression, ROW_NUMBER() and PARTITON thing..... )

Answer (score 1):

Apart from [Joachim Isaksson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26135137/3682599),you try this method also

```
SELECT C1, string_agg(C2, ',') as c2
FROM (
      SELECT *, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY C2)-1)/3 as row_num
      FROM atable) t
GROUP BY C1,row_num
ORDER BY c2
```